# Web Site download speed when using separate CSS file versus HTML style tag

Tags: html, css

Will a server be able to present a site more quickly if we have all the CSS as part of the style section of the html rather than having a separate linked stylesheet in a separate file?

Comment: I'm assuming that you meant download, not upload, and any time you link to another file, the browser spends time making a connection, so yes, it would be a little slower to link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the much better practice to have separate CSS files not only for your organization purposes and for the others who want to later contribute to fix the website but also because this strategy allows you to use the browser's cache.

https://css-tricks.com/one-two-three/

Yes there might be a slight improvement in Load time by having it all on one CSS or even "better" within the same HTML page but there's a reason that basically no sites do that, the reason is that it is basically irrelevant speedwise, it is unconventional and doesn't apply the browser's cache feature.

When using multiple jQuery plugins, with specific css files referencing them:
In that case you may want to use just one separate CSS file for sure, but still better than having a messy giant HTML file with a huge style section.

It also can even be faster in some cases....

Lets say you have an HTML page for the homepage/landingpage /index.html... This has its own style parameters and those are all in the small stylesheet called index.css (for the sake of this example).

The next page is one of the article on the homepage articles.html. It has it's own stylesheet link "articles.css" and that has it's own small rules for style.

If you combined articles.css with index.css then you have a massive file there which will take a long time to load but the user might not even click on article and then they just loaded articles.css's contents for nothing.

This particular site might have a comments link a user link and another dozen pages which the user may never click on. Why force the user to download css files for things they will never see?

When the user clicks on back to return to the homepage ... the other stylesheet is already cached. So it won't matter.

Comment: I see many websites having 100s of CSS different files. I know it provides clearity for them to work with others. But speed is of the highest priority, then will there be any difference if we have only single css file instead of the 100?

Comment: Another great reason for them to have 100s of CSS files is because they downloaded some from here and there or they may want one person to handle one file versus another. The speed difference is marginal but yes I think it would be faster to have just one file, by about .1second or something and as soon as that is cached it would matter even less, meaning on the next visit to the site or even when visiting another page in the same website.

Comment: I just added another hypothetical.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot to consider when it comes to CSS delivery. Technically inlining CSS is faster, but not always the best practice as it can become tricky to maintain if multiple pages share the same properties.

There's some great articles by Google on this subject:

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/InlineCSS
https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery

You might also want to look into minifying css, as that can slightly improve load times also. Minifying eliminates all spacing and can be inlined or added to an external stylesheet. For example:

```
  div.classy span, div.classy img {
    display: block;
    border: none !important;
    background: none !important;
  }
```

Would become:

```
 dif.classy span,div.classy img{display:block;border:none!important;background:none!important}
```